# Subdomain on azurewebsites.net?

Tags: azure, subdomain, azure-web-app-service

To avoid namespace collisions on azurewebsites.net I prefix my websites with a string. Example `foo-app1.azurewebsites.net` and `foo-app2.azurewebsites.net`, etc so in this case they are grouped under the "foo-" prefix.

However a subdomain would be a nice way of grouping websites.

Is it possible to group websites as `app1.foo.azurewebsites.net` and `app2.foo.azurewebsites.net`?

Comment: Why are you wanting to group the websites?

Comment: To avoid namespace collision. Common names are usually taken by other people, hence I prefix them so I can use those names. I wanted to use `app1` but it was already taken, so I used `foo-app1`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'grouping'? Is this for human readability or to achieve some other technical need?

Comment: Well many names are taken by other people already, so I need to make my names unique hence I prefix them with something. But thought a subdomain would be a better way to to avoid namespace collisions.

Comment: why not buy a domain name and use that?

Comment: I already have a domain name. Don't they need a name on azurewebsites too though?

Comment: When using a custom domain name the Azure name for the web app should no longer be used by the outside once you bind that custom domain to your web app. As for the Azure web app domain name I use the following naming convention to help me easily identify my sites. DEPT-APPNAME-ENV-REGION-AP (billing-accountingAPI-eu-ap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to group websites as app1.foo.azurewebsites.net and app2.foo.azurewebsites.net?

For azure app service, `app1.foo.azurewebsites.net` and `app2.foo.azurewebsites.net` are two independent web apps. In order to group your websites, I assumed that you could configure the custom domain name for your Azure websites.

Assuming that your custom domain name is `contoso.com`. You could map your subdomains against the same azure web app as follow:

```
app1.contoso.com -> {app_name}.azurewebsites.net
app2.contoso.com -> {app_name}.azurewebsites.net
```

Also, you could map your subdomains to your different azure web apps as follows:

```
app1.contoso.com -> {app_name_01}.azurewebsites.net
app2.contoso.com -> {app_name_02}.azurewebsites.net
```

More details about how to map your custom DNS name to Azure Web Apps, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of custom domain, but I was thinking of grouping without using a custom domain. Yes, those would be two indenpendent web apps, but is it possible to place all my apps under a subdomain of azurewebsites.net?

Comment: You can not place all your apps under a subdomain of azurewebsites.net. AFAIK, you could leverage the virtual directory for deploying multiple application to a single Azure Website, at this point, you apps would look like: `contoso.azurewebsites.net/app1/`, `contoso.azurewebsites.net/app2/`. More details, you could refer to [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/). Per my understanding, the custom domain is the better way for you to achieve your purpose.